# table with caption in letter class

Tags: tables, captions, letters

Self explanatory title question: How do I get to produce a table with caption in a letter class?

A working example would be great.

Comment: What do you mean with `all` option from TeX.SX? The `letter` class does not define `table` floats

Comment: I meant workarounds suggested in TeX.SX - How do I get around the problem of including table with caption?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `letter` class does not define the float types of `table` or `figure`, so `\captionof` from `caption` package will fail as will `\caption` of course too (since there are no `figure` or `table` environments).

However, it is possible to provide a 'fake' table environment with `\DeclareFloatingEnvironment` from `newfloat`.

```
\documentclass{letter}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{newfloat}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=lot]{table}

\address{Ministry of Silly Walks\\ The Embankment\\ London}
\name{Mr. Gumby}
\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Ann Elk}
\opening{Dear Sirs, I wish to report a burglary}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
  1 & 2 & 3 
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{My nice table}
\end{center}
\closing{And now for something completely different}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: IMHO `minipage+centering` could be better than `center` to avoid page break.

Comment: wouldn't `lot` make more sense than `lof`?

Comment: @touhami: that's not the point ;-) The point is that there's no float at all for a `letter`

Comment: @Mark: Of course, I was in a hurry. Thanks, I've changed it to `lot`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer you're right :-)

Comment: Is it possible to reference a label to the table?

Comment: Why do you define a "table" float in the header, but then use the "center" environment in the letter itself? You don't ever use "\begin{table}", is this intended?
It seems that your MWE doesn't actually generate a float. I tried it in an example where the table would be put on a new page and the "\begin{center}" approach doesn't do this. Using "\begin{table}" actually produces a float which is then put on a new page (if the processor thinks it fits better).

Answer (score 3):

After all, it’s also possible to use the `articoletteracdp` document class (disclosure: I am the author of this class), which provides the ability to write letters divided into `\section`s and `\paragraph`s, and also to include the ordinary `figure` and `table` environments.  It supports `\tableofcontents`, `\listoffigures`, and `\listoftables`, too, on a letter-by-letter basis.

This class, however, has its own idiosyncrasies: it has a peculiar way of invoking the `babel` package, to mention one, and it places the sender’s address on the left and the adressee’s on the right, because it was written to support Italian conventions; this can be customized, anyway.  But besides this, it’s very old: it dates back to 2000.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,smartindent]{articoletteracdp}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % Unrelated to the question, but I like it.

\usepackage[english]{cdpbabel}  % required by the document class, also loads 
                                % the "babel" package.
\usepackage{lipsum}

\address{Ministry of Silly Walks\\ The Embankment\\ London}
\name{Mr. Gumby}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Ann Elk}

\opening{Dear Sirs,}

I wish to report a burglary.

\listoftables

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[tbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
      1 & 2 & 3 
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{My nice table}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2]

\closing{And now for something completely different!}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

The output follows:

[image: Output of the code]

Comment: Another strange point about your document class is that it seems to reproduce content of my example out of the box ;-) (+1)